# Selected value of ChoiceField created by ForeignKey is not displayed in form

Tags: django, django-forms

**Background**

I have a model

```
class Contact(models.Model):
       permanent_state      = models.ForeignKey(State)
```

in form.py

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
```

in view.py

```
main(request):
     contact = Contact.objects.values().get(employee_id = emp) 
     print contact
     form  = ContactForm(initial = contact)
     print form
     return render(request,"dashboard/main.html",{  'form' : form})
```

problem: the form generates a drop down select html tag of permanent_state but does not show the state.instead it shows "------"

print output:

```
{ 'permanent_state_id': 2}



<tr><th><label for="id_permanent_state">Permanent state:</label></th><td><select id="id_permanent_state" name="permanent_state">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="1">Bengal</option>
<option value="2">Uttar Pradesh</option>
<option value="3">Tripura</option>
<option value="4">Tamil Nadu</option>
<option value="5">Sikkim</option>
```

But if I print the dict contact it gives me permanent_state value as 2.
The selected value is correct in django admin app showing Uttar Pradesh

Please Help

Comment: Can you paste "dashboard/main.html" template? In order for the HTML form to have the right selection the HTML must be rendered in the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
contact = Contact.objects.get(employee_id = emp) 
#Note that get throws an error if get() does not return a single value

form  = ContactForm(instance = contact)
```

Relevant [documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm)